# sIFR works but it pushes my content after rendering a little bit to the bottom

Tags: sifr

i want to use the siFR on my website but i have one question. I have implemented sIFR and it seems to work, but when it load and renders the new headline it "pushs" my content to the bottom. i think 10px or so.

Why does this happen?

Can someone help please?

Heres my sifr-config.js

```
var futura = { src: 'http://www.bogazci.com/wp-content/themes/bogazci_09/sifr/flash/gppmc.swf' };
sIFR.activate(futura);

sIFR.replace(futura, {
  selector: 'h1',
  css: '.sIFR-root { background-color: #ffffff; color: #960000; }',
  ratios: [8, 1.42, 11, 1.38, 17, 1.32, 21, 1.3, 23, 1.27, 30, 1.28, 44, 1.26, 65, 1.25, 66, 1.24, 67, 1.25, 70, 1.24, 71, 1.25, 118, 1.24, 119, 1.23, 1.24],
});
```

Heres the sifr.css

```
@media screen {
  /* Example: */
  .sIFR-active h1 {
    visibility: hidden;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
}
```

heres my page.css

```
body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #666;
}

h1 {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    /* letter-spacing:-1px; */
    color:#333; /* 16216c, 333, d90000, 16216c */
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

heres the implementation:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/sIFR/css/sifr.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/sIFR/js/sifr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/sIFR/js/sifr-debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/sIFR/js/sifr-config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


..
..

<h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof sIFR == "function"){
    sIFR.replaceElement("h1", named({sFlashSrc: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/sIFR/gppmc.swf", sColor: "#999999"}));
    sIFR();
};
</script>
</body>
```

i dont know. please help.

Heres my page:

http://www.bogazci.com/index.php/services

thank you

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of extra space inside the Flash movie. Use the `tuneHeight` and `offsetTop` arguments to correct for this.

Also, you should remove the config for sIFR 2 that's still included in the page.